# Three.js flipSided property

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can't seem to find the flipSided property in the documentation for material.

I have a mesh that has 2 sides but I would like to flip it's sides.

Does anyone know where that property went?

Edit: To clarify I meant to flip the sides of a two sided object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide) for help upgrading to the current version. There you will find the following:

`doubleSided` / `flipSided` properties moved from `Object3D` to `Material`'s `side` property (`THREE.FrontSide`, `THREE.BackSide` and `THREE.DoubleSide`).

For example,

```
material.side = THREE.BackSide;
```

three.js r.62 - r.109

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant like... flipping the sides of a two sided mesh? Is there a function for that?

Comment: No, there is no such function. But your question is a good one, and will be helpfull to others. Please remember to "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark. Thank you.