# Drawing mirror object in ThreeJS

Tags: matrix, graphics, three.js, geometry, mirroring

I am trying to develop a mirror of an object in threejs.
I want to implement same as shown in video.
https://youtu.be/8KT7PBfJYpI
There could be any object; line, circle, arc geometry line. (dotted object in video)
When user moves the mouse, white line is drawn, which is a reference line, or a mirror.
Dotted object should get its mirror copy according to white line which is reference line.
How this could be achieved?

Objects are made like this:

```
lineGeometry():BufferGeometry {
        // geometry
        const geometry:BufferGeometry = new BufferGeometry();
        this.positions = new Float32Array(this.MAX_POINTS * 3);
        geometry.setAttribute('position', new BufferAttribute(this.positions, 3));
        return geometry;
    }

    lineShape( geometry:BufferGeometry ):Line {
        // material
        const material:LineDashedMaterial = new LineDashedMaterial(
            { color: this.MS.color.LINE, dashSize: 0, gapSize: 0 }
        );
        // line
        const line:Line = new Line(geometry, material);
        return line;
    }
```

Now on mouse move, I am writing a mirror function. I need some logic, how to achieve this.

```
mirror( relative:Vector3 ) {
        //get reference line angle
        const lineArray = this.line.geometry.attributes.position.array;
        const lineX1:number = lineArray[0];
        const lineY1:number = lineArray[1];
        const lineX2:number = lineArray[3];
        const lineY2:number = lineArray[4];
        let lineAngle:number = this.FS.get_angle_between_points( lineX1, lineY1, lineX2, lineY2 );
        lineAngle = this.FS.radians_to_degrees( lineAngle );

        

    }
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried in code via a minimal and reproducible example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'd just ask the guy who uploaded the video to Youtube.

Comment: I uploaded the video. I have this in some application