# mapping of image on sphere using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to UV map a cube-map texture onto a sphere. I have tried to Map a cube-map onto a cube and it was pretty easy. I had this image which was mapped onto the cube as follows:
Click here to open image

This is the final output (with a different image, of same type)[Click here to open the Output][2]

This is how I carried out the UV mapping for the aforementioned task:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 10); 
 
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/texture-atlas.jpg') } );
```

There are few things that I found in OpenGL, but almost nothing for Three.js

If you can come up with anything that'll help me in executing this, it'll be a great help. If possible, please show me how to map one image onto corresponding part of the sphere and I'll do it for the rest of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `SphereGeometry` does not have vertices in the correct locations to achieve the mapping you want. However, you can easily create a suitable geometry by morphing `BoxGeometry` into a sphere.

```
// geometry
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8 );

// morph box into a sphere
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i ++ ) {

    geometry.vertices[ i ].normalize().multiplyScalar( 10 ); // or whatever size you want

}

// texture is a collage; set offset/repeat per material index
var repeat = new THREE.Vector2( 1/3, 1/2 );
var offsets = [ 
    new THREE.Vector2( 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 0, 1/2 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 1/3, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 1/3, 1/2 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 2/3, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 2/3, 1/2 )
];

// redefine vertex normals consistent with a sphere; reset UVs
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {

    var face = geometry.faces[ i ];

    face.vertexNormals[ 0 ].copy( geometry.vertices[ face.a ] ).normalize();
    face.vertexNormals[ 1 ].copy( geometry.vertices[ face.b ] ).normalize();
    face.vertexNormals[ 2 ].copy( geometry.vertices[ face.c ] ).normalize();

    var uvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ];

    for ( var j = 0; j < 3; j ++ ) {

        uvs[ i ][ j ].multiply( repeat ).add( offsets[ face.materialIndex ] );

    }

    // face.normal - will not be used; don't worry about it

}

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load( 'texture.jpg' );

// mesh
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture } ) );
scene.add( mesh );
```

three.js r.77

Comment: Hi, Mr. @WestLangley
Thanks! I tried to execute this, and it works fine. The cube gets morphed into a sphere. There's another hurdle that I have come across.
This is what the result looks like (after incorporating your code): http://postimg.org/image/ro54xtarr/ 
I have used the same UV mapping as I used earlier, and I know it's wrong. But I am unable to think of a proper way to alter the UV mapping, because there are too many vertice now. Please help me to figure this out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use http://i.stack.imgur.com/KNtHH.jpg, or is it OK to load 6 separate images?

Comment: I have to use that single image which has all the six sub-images. Is there a way?

Comment: Most probably, the reason why you asked me if a collage is a requirement or not, is because if it is not, we can load the six separate images on the six faces of the cube and then morph it into a sphere. It can be certainly done in this manner. But is there a way to do it without having to load the six images separately? I am eagerly waiting for for reply...

Comment: Correct. I modified my answer to show how to use `offset/repeat` with a single collage. You just have to load the collage 6 times. I normally do not provide this kind of help, but your question was interesting to me, so you benefit... I hope this wasn't an assignment...

Comment: I don't quite understand this. I am trying. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. This was not an assignment. :-)

Comment: Provide a live link to show what you are doing if you are stuck. It is not hard.

Comment: I am trying to visualize what you tried to do. Of the six lines that you have in the materials array, the first line passes the args 'path', '0/3', '0/3' to the loadTexture function. This function loads the image onto the morphed 3D object with offset as (0, 0) and repeat as (1/3,1/3). Going as per the documentation, repeat (1/3,1/3) would mean that the texture is repeated 1/3 times in each direction U and V. Now, Why would you do that? Shouldn't be it texture.repeat.set( 1/3, 1/2 ); ?

Comment: And one more necessary question, that I have to ask. I understand that we are loading the same image six times, which is a bit inefficient way of doing this. If my image is too heavy(or let's say it is a video texture), will it not talk too much time to render 6 textures than rendering 1 texture? Is there a much more efficient method?

Comment: (1) yes. typo. (2) update the uv's and use the first method. The box geometry has a materialIndex for each side. Updating the UVs is easy, it turns out. Updated answer.

Comment: Now that the UVs have been updated, I don't have to change anything right? I mean, earlier we had the problem because on using more number of segments to build the cube, we created a lot more vertices and that messed up the UV mapping..

Comment: Why does the entire morphing through normalization thing nullify, when I move my camera to the center of the 3D object? I just added:
 `    mesh.scale.x = -1;
       mesh.position.z = 0;`
And this is what I got? [Image] ( http://imgur.com/XMTKAzW )

Comment: You need to make a new post at this point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824650/three-js-how-to-flip-normals-after-negative-scale/16840273#16840273

Comment: I made a new post. Any help from your end will be appreciated. Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956358/flipping-the-normals-of-geometry-in-three-js

Comment: Sorry, I have given you all the help I can. This question was an exception. Good luck!