# Flipping y-axis for path/shape object

Tags: three.js

I converted some SVG to HTML5 canvas using http://mtcc.com/site/jscanvastest.html based on https://code.google.com/p/canvg/ .  I use part of the output to construct THREE.Shape -object, using lineTo, moveTo, and bezierCurveTo.

Because orientation of the y-axis differs between HTML5 canvas and three.js, I am looking for a way to flip the y-axis in three.js .

Following two approaches that do not work for THREE.Shape.  They both flip the surface orientation as well, so the mesh becomes visible on the wrong side, thus negating the effect of flipping.

1)

```
geom.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4(1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0));
```

2)

```
mesh.scale.set( 1, -1, 1 );
```

Example geometry that should produce a letter "L"

```
var ctx = new THREE.Shape();
ctx.moveTo(50,10);
ctx.lineTo(50,80);
ctx.lineTo(90,80);
ctx.lineTo(90,60);
ctx.lineTo(69,60);
ctx.lineTo(60,10);
var geom = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( ctx );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geom, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x000000 } ) );
```

Comment: One way to solve this is to take changeFaceOrientation(geometry) function from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/388 . But then the shape renders in black color and not in the defined color.  Hmm.

Comment: Relatedd tip: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431316/how-to-toggle-threejs-outer-face-direction/17431668#17431668