# Negative scale in axis Y using applyMatrix does not work

Tags: three.js

I am creating a web page to illustrate the 3D transformations and I am using Three.js. I have detected a problem when I try to do a negative scale in Y axis. In this case, the object is not affected (a face inversion should be done but it doesn't). However, for negative scales in axis X or Z it works well. Any help? This is my code:

```
var m = new THREE.Matrix4(
    scaleX, 0,      0,      0,
    0,      scaleY, 0,      0,
    0,      0,      scaleZ, 0,
    0,      0,      0,      1 
);
cube.applyMatrix(m);
```

If I use cube.scale.set(scaleX,scaleY,scaleZ) the first transformation is performed rightly, but I can't link with other transformations. I need for my application that the user can do several transformations in the same scene.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824650/three-js-how-to-flip-normals-after-negative-scale/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469270/transforming-vertex-normals-in-three-js/

Answer (score -1):

Your matrix is not correct.
Try with :

```
var m = new THREE.Matrix4(
    1, 0, 0, scaleX,
    0, 1, 0, scaleY,
    0, 0, 1, scaleZ,
    0, 0, 0, 1
);

cube.applyMatrix(m);
```

Comment: That is for repositioning an object, not for scaling it. After applying this matrix your values are the new x, y and z coordinates of the position of the object.